# How to change line after navbar-text

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Here is my code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark  ">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOREM IPSUM</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav  ml-auto">
                <p class="navbar-text">lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOREM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">IPSUM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">DOLOR</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The result produced by this:
[image]

How to change line after "lorem ipsum dolor" and show my all nav links(in same line) in separate line , I have tried `display:block` but it is not working. Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers helped or worked , trick was to create a separate div and float it to right side with navbar text and a collapsible navbar inside it , here is the code :

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark  ">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                     
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOREM IPSUM</a>
                     
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="float-right ">
      <p class="navbar-text">lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav  ">
                       
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOREM</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">IPSUM</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">DOLOR</a>
                          </li>
                        
                      </ul>
                    </div>
  </div>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To display nav links in separate line and create a vertical navbar remove `.navbar-expand-sm` class from `nav`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOREM IPSUM</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav  ml-auto">
                <p class="navbar-text">lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOREM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">IPSUM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">DOLOR</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `remove .navbar-expand-sm` , this hides nav in laptops as well , I want to hide only in mobile

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOREM IPSUM</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-wrap" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <div class="w-100"><p class="navbar-text">lorem Ipsum Dolor</p></div>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOREM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">IPSUM</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">DOLOR</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this shows everything in different line I just want to break line after `lorem Ipsum Dolor`

Comment: I've just edited the snippet html add class "flex-wrap" into navbar-collapse and then  <div class="w-100"><p class="navbar-text">lorem Ipsum Dolor</p></div>

Comment: I have solved check my solution , thanks for your efforts